# TikZ Label multiple plots outside of axis box

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels

I'm endeavouring to make a graph similar to the following using PgfPlots and TikZ.

[image: Multiple y plots with labels on the left]

I can make all of this work, except for the placement of the `R=2`, `R=3`, `R=5`, and `R=10` markers on the left-hand side.

It would be nice if PgfPlots could place these automatically - any thoughts as to how? Alternatively, how could they be placed manually?

Thanks!

Comment: You can place them by adding `node [pos=0] {$R=2$}` at the end of your `\addplot` command. By default, they'll be clipped away, though, so you'll have to add `clip=false` to the `axis` options.

Comment: @Jake, that worked perfectly, except that I needed `node [pos=0,left] {$R=2$}. Please write up your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can place nodes along a plot by including `node [pos=<fraction>] {<text>}` at the end of the `\addplot` command, where `pos=0` is the beginning and `pos=1` is the end of the plot.

By default, objects that are defined as part of the `\addplot` commands are clipped at the axis boundaries, so your nodes would not be visible in this case. To disable the clipping, set `clip=false` in the `axis` options.

If you need the clipping, but still want to label your plots outside the axis boundaries, see [PgfPlots with labeled plots extend outside the graph box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63832/pgfplots-with-labeled-plots-extend-outside-the-graph-box) for a (slightly hackish) alternative.