# PgfPlots with labeled plots extend outside the graph box

Tags: pgfplots, labels

Sorry for the confusing title.

The MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
        \begin{axis}[ylabel=Y-Axis, xlabel=X-Axis, xmin=0, xmax=10, ymin=0, ymax=12, clip=false, yticklabel pos=right, ylabel near ticks]
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0.01,0.1,0.9}{
            \addplot[mark=none, domain=0.0:10, thick] {-ln(#1/5^x)/ln(5)} node [pos=0,left] {$c_x=#1$};
        }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

produces the following graph

[image: Graph showing plot extending outside of the box.]

This is just what I want... except that the c_x=0.01 line is extending outside of the box!

Setting `clip=false` is necessary to get the `c_x=` labels to show up, but I think that it's producing this side-effect.

How can I have my cake and eat it too? That is, how can I have my automagically-positioned labels on the left and my graph nicely contained on the right?

Comment: One option is to use `clip=true`, and use `pos=0.5, sloped, above` option to the node.

Comment: Quite so, @PeterGrill. I'll probably go with Jake's answer for this in order to preserve symmetry between several similarly-styled graphs I have for which internal placement of the node would over-crowd the data. But I would upvote your comment as an answer.

Comment: I am not quite in the same league as Jake. He is definitely one of the pgfplots guru.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ah, tricky one!

Here's a new command `\sneakylabel{<label text>}` that you can use instead of the `node [pos=0] ...` method.

```
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0.01,0.1,0.9}{
    \addplot[mark=none, domain=0.0:10, thick] {-ln(#1/5^x)/ln(5)};
    \sneakylabel{$c_x=#1$}
}
```

will give you

[image]

What it does first is position a `coordinate` at the start of the plot, with a unique name (which uses the label text, so if you need several identical labels, we'll have to tweak this a bit). Then it adds a `\node` command for the actual label to the `after end axis`-list, which contains code that will be executed after the clipping has been performed. The `node` is positioned using the `coordinate` we saved before.

Enjoy the cake!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand{\sneakylabel}[1]{
    \coordinate (sneakylabel{#1}) at (current plot begin);
    \pgfplotsset{
        after end axis/.append code={
            \node [anchor=east] at (sneakylabel{#1}){#1};
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
        \begin{axis}[ylabel=Y-Axis, xlabel=X-Axis, xmin=0, xmax=10, ymin=0, ymax=12, yticklabel pos=right, ylabel near ticks,]
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0.01,0.1,0.9}{
            \addplot[mark=none, domain=0.0:10, thick] {-ln(#1/5^x)/ln(5)};
            \sneakylabel{$c_x=#1$}
        }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the option `restrict y to domain*=0:12`.

Comment: Unless your sampling points are exactly on the intersection of the line and the axis border, this will introduce a bend in the plot. Also, it will draw the plot along the axis border, so if you use something like `red, thick` for the plot, you'll be able to see the truncated segment.